Program arguments for remote debugging of a linux app in Visual Studio
I need to cross debug a remote linux application from Visual Studio.
The application accepts one argument.
Running the program on the remote machine, passing the expected argument
./S_main_Linux_11.4_x86_64.exe RUN_Test/input.py

works just fine.
But when I try to run a debug session from Visual Studio I get issues.
Without that input argument the debug session initiates properly (although the program will complain when it realizes that no arguments have been passed), which let me think that I configured the other parameters properly.
If I pass the argument as shown in picture, the debug session fails. I tried to add the input between single quotations, double quotation marks, I tried to using single slash, double slash, a backslash with escape char (\\) but no luck.
It looks like there is something going on when the argument string is sent to the remote machine, but I don't have idea what that could be. Mabe some settings about the character encoding?

